# Android -- How to destroy an object after its animation has stopped?

Tags: android, animation

After an ImageView translates off the screen via a TranslateAnimation object, I want to set the ImageView as null. So really my question is how does one know when an animation has completed without resorting to polling to objects position or other variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register an [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) with the `Animation`, and listen for `onAnimationEnd()`.

Comment: i have your book, been meaning to look at it.

Comment: @farm ostrich: You will find `AnimationListener` in [The Busy Coder's Guide to Advanced Android Development](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid), in the chapter on animation.